# How to make a diff branches with JGit?

Tags: branch, diff, jgit

Use JGit. Need to know the difference in the branches.
How to run a command JGit API:
 **git diff --name-status ..origin**

Comment: What specifically are you having a problem with? Have you looked at the [JGit API](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git.html) at all?

Comment: Yes, I have used the JGit API. I don't understand, how to run the command `git diff --name-status ..origin` with  `DiffCommand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DiffCommand by creating AbstractTreeIterator instaces for the branches and then use the DiffCommand to return you a list of differences between the two branches:

```
// the diff works on TreeIterators, we prepare two for the two branches
AbstractTreeIterator oldTreeParser = prepareTreeParser(repository, "refs/heads/oldbranch");
AbstractTreeIterator newTreeParser = prepareTreeParser(repository, "refs/heads/master");

// then the procelain diff-command returns a list of diff entries
List<DiffEntry> diff = new Git(repository).diff().setOldTree(oldTreeParser).setNewTree(newTreeParser).call();
for(DiffEntry entry : diff) {
    System.out.println("Entry: " + entry);
}
```

The full example including creating the AbstractTreeIterator can now be found [as part of my jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowBranchDiff.java)